# Tikz Bar graphs with many coordinates per y value

Tags: pgfplots, ticks, ybar

I have a few problems with the following code:

```
\begin{figure}
\caption{test}\label{fig:sourceType}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            xbar,
            reverse legend,
            width = \textwidth,
            height = \textheight,
            symbolic y coords={motorway,primary,secondary,tertiary,unclassified/unknown,service},
            xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick*100}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\%},
            xlabel = Relative frequency
        ]

        \addplot[blue!20!black,fill=blue!10!white] coordinates {
        (0.0135,motorway)
        (0.02,primary)
        (0.0797,secondary)
        (0.1027,tertiary)
        (0.1453,unclassified/unknown)
        (0.1904,service)
        };

        \addplot[blue!20!black,fill=blue!40!white] coordinates {
        (0.0129,motorway)
        (0.0192,primary)
        (0.0821,secondary)
        (0.1121,tertiary)
        (0.1656,unclassified/unknown)
        (0.1762,service)
        };

        \addplot[blue!20!black,fill=blue!70!white] coordinates {
        (0.0119,motorway)
        (0.0199,primary)
        (0.0767,secondary)
        (0.1117,tertiary)
        (0.1751,unclassified/unknown)
        (0.1813,service)
        };

        \addplot[blue!20!black,fill=blue!100!white] coordinates {
        (0.0154,motorway)
        (0.0231,primary)
        (0.0805,secondary)
        (0.1052,tertiary)
        (0.1444,unclassified/unknown)
        (0.1871,service)
        };

        \addplot[red!20!black,fill=red!80!white] coordinates {
        (0.0159,motorway)
        (0.0158,primary)
        (0.072,secondary)
        (0.0895,tertiary)
        (0.1189,unclassified/unknown)
        (0.2129,service)
        };
\legend {Stgt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

The result looks like this:
[image]

How do I get rid of the duplicate y-labels, keeping only the center ones (it needs to be clear which 5 bars belong to which label)? The height is only chosen to be maximum for the bars not to overlap and can be changed at any time. Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Hi, welcome. Try adding either `ytick distance=1` or `ytick=data` to the the `axis` option.